# Function parameters in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to calculate standard statistical size (i.e. variance) for each column in data table, that can be created in following way:

```
library(data.table)
x <- rnorm(10)
y <- rnorm(10)
z <- rnorm(10)
dt <- data.table(x, y, z)
dt[,lapply(.SD, var)]
```

And it works perfectly. However, if I have NAs in my data table, I want to use function argument like:

```
dt[,lapply(.SD, var(na.rm = T))]
```

And now I am getting error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'var(x = dt, na.rm = T)' is not a function, character or symbol
```

I cannot come up with the solution for this one. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Read the documentation of `lapply()`: FUN= is a function (not a call to a function)

```
dt[, lapply(.SD, var, na.rm=TRUE)]
```